# Hide/Show Table based off of drop down menu selection HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to hide the second table below and make it appear when customers select the debit option from the drop down menu at the top. I'm relatively new to this so any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<table width="723" height="75" border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="248" scope="col"><span style="font-size: 13px">Payment 
     Method:</span>
        <select>
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="tracer ach credit">Credit</option>
      <option value="tracer ach debit">Debit</option>
    </select>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table width="723" height="558" border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">
      <td height="40" colspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="24" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 13px">Bank 
    Account:</span>&nbsp; &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td height="26"><textarea rows="1" cols="50"> 
              </textarea>&nbsp;</td>
      </td>
      <span style="text-align: center">
            </div>
            </span>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There is only one table in your code ... where is the second table that you are trying to hide?

Comment: Sorry I meant I am trying to hide that first table. The one that asks for a  Bank account. I was considering the first section with the drop down as a table.

Comment: This is invalid HTML `<span style="text-align: center">
            </div>
            </span>` and where is the script you are trying to hide the table with?

Comment: I don't have a script to hide the table yet. would I just use something like this table#tableId {
  display: none;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `id="table2"` to your table and this `CSS` to start hidden:

```
#table2 {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

And add to your `<select>` the [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange)`="ShowHide(this)"` every change in select call the `ShowHide` function.

With `javascript`  add this function to turn [visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) the table if the option selected is debit:

```
function ShowHide(select){
  var table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
  if(select.value == "tracer ach debit"){
      table2.style.visibility="visible";
  }else{
    table2.style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

**Online example:**

```js
function ShowHide(select){
  var table2 = document.getElementById("table2");
  if(select.value == "tracer ach debit"){
      table2.style.visibility="visible";
  }else{
    table2.style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}
```

```css
#table2 {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<table width="300" height="75" border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <span style="font-size: 13px">Payment Method:</span>
        <select id="select" onchange="ShowHide(this)">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="tracer ach credit">Credit</option>
          <option value="tracer ach debit">Debit</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table width="300" height="300" border="2" id="table2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <span style="font-size: 13px">Bank Account:</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
        <span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function paymentChangeHandler(event) {
  var value = event.target.value;
  var bank = document.getElementById("bank_info");
  if (value.indexOf('debit') !== -1) {
    bank.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    bank.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}

var selector = document.getElementById("payment_method");
selector.onchange = paymentChangeHandler;
```

```html
<table width="723" height="75" border="2">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="248" scope="col"><span style="font-size: 13px">Payment 
     Method:</span>
        <select id="payment_method">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="tracer ach credit">Credit</option>
      <option value="tracer ach debit">Debit</option>
    </select>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table width="723" height="558" border="2" id="bank_info" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: center; font-size: 13px;">
      <td height="40" colspan="2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="24" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 13px">Bank 
    Account:</span>&nbsp; &nbsp;
      </td>
      <td height="26"><textarea rows="1" cols="50"> 
              </textarea>&nbsp;</td>
      <span style="text-align: center">
            </span>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Add **id's** for payment method drop down control and bank table and add style **visibility:hidden** to bank table.

Comment: Thanks for your help!